Working with extremely large public datasets - software constantly freezes (ArcGIS Pro 3.4.0)
I have a map layer of drone flight plans from the last year, showing all of the polygons where my organization flew drones at different survey locations (to take vegetation imagery). This is spread out over 3 different states. I am trying to use the public SSURGO 'USA Soils Map Units' data layer to run a 1 to many spatial join with my flight map polygons and determine the soil type within each flight plan. However, I am finding that the size of this dataset makes it extremely difficult to work with, because every time I try to do something (even simple actions like selecting and de-selecting a feature) often result in my software/computer freezing up. Am I wrong to believe this is due to the size of the soils data layer? It has over 36 million records and probably over 70 different fields, many of which are not relevant to the analysis I am trying to run. Is there a good way for me to simplify this dataset before I run my spatial join so that my computer doesn't have so much trouble with processing? How do people run analyses with extremely large datasets like this without it crashing your computer?

What is the specification of your computer? here is a quick insight on windows maximum amount of RAM Windows 11 Home: 128 GB
Windows 11 Pro: 2 TB
Windows 11 Pro for Workstations: 6 TB

Are you pulling this dataset from the internet or can you localise your data?

There are multiple ways to improve performance. Firstly as @Mapperz hints, streaming data over the internet is not going to work, can you store the soils data locally? A quick review of the Web Soil Survey website it looks like you can download areas of interest or by state, but you probably need to merge the data back into a single dataset. Having it local on your machine alone will give you a significance performance boost.
What ever you do don't use shapefiles, merge it or import it into a file geodatabase. The geodatabase maintains a spatial index automatically.
When you run the spatial join set the processing extent to your flight polygon data, that will limit what it needs to access.
With you data local, in a geodatabase and smarter use of the tools your spatial join should takes less than a minute, if not seconds.
